# Непреднамеренно выполняется файл при запуске pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

При открытие проекта pycharm, в консоли начинает непреднамеренно выполнятся файл org.py(стоит отметить что виртуальная среда, у меня сразу на 2 проектах), файл этот находится в этой же директории, также если запустить любой другой файл в этой же директории например - asdasd.py, в вкладке run напечатает - `C:\for\anaconda3\envs\fowever\python.exe C:/Users/Public/overlay/asdasd.py`, но начнет выполнять файл org.py вместо asdads.py. Первая строчка в консоли - `C:\for\anaconda3\envs\fowever\python.exe "C:/Users/Владимир/AppData/Local/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=62303`. Пару дней назад, я запускал локальный сервер, примерно такой строчкой(Возможно нет, но подобной - точно) - `python3 -m http.server`. После запуска сервера, я многократно как перезапускал так и выключал компьютер.Как прекратить эти непреднамеренные действия. Возможно я написал много лишнего или наоборот не написал важные аспекты, написал всё что могло гипотетически как-то повлиять.

Я РЕШИЛ ПРОБЛЕМУ. Я пересоздал файл org.py, тоесть удалил и заново сделал его, теперь всё работает корректно, при открытие проекта в консоли ничего не выполнятся, и любой другой файл работает корректно, но всё равно есть вопрос, что это было?